# I need a 12V battery supply for a device can I just connect four 3V batteries?

Tags: electric-circuits, voltage, batteries

its for a modem which requires a 12v adapter, 1amp. So I tried connecting 4 batteries and also 5 but it never turned on and I couldn't figure why?

Comment: What makes you think you can't?

Comment: each battery in the series add it's electrical potential to the next.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: It's for a modem, and it says I need an adapter to convert it to 12v but I figured why can't you just add 4 batteries in series or even 5 due to some internal resistance, and it doesn't work. Why is it so?

Comment: Check the voltage of the batteries, is it really 12V or so?

Comment: Yes each battery is 3 volts

Answer (score 1):

You can. Bear in mind that a "4V" battery may not be exactly 4V, so you won't get exactly 12V, but thats fine if your 12V device is designed to be battery powered.

The only thing you need to watch for is the current rating of your batteries, and the maximum discharge. What type of batteries are you using? (Li-Ion, alkaline, NiMH, etc)

Comment: I needed it for a modem, for which I don't have the adapter. So I figured why not just add 4 or 5 batteries in series apart from exceeding he 1Ampere current limit there shouldn't be any issue right? But it doesn't light on even for a second.